# deserialize conplex json and access property in xamarin

Tags: json, xamarin.android

hello everyone i am fetching some json data from server and i want to desalinize that complex json and add in custom object and i dont know how to access that property value .

Here is the json data format

```
    [
 {
"Id": 1,
"AlbumId": 2,
"Name": "sample string 3",
"Url": "sample string 4",
"ShareUrl": "sample string 5",
"Selected": true,
"Comment": "sample string 6",
"Album": {
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "sample string 2",
  "PhotoGrapherId": 3,
  "ClientId": 4,
  "EventType": "sample string 5",
  "EventDate": "2017-10-11T12:06:33.735998+05:30",
  "Status": "sample string 7",
  "Url": "sample string 8",
  "CreatedOn": "2017-10-11T12:06:33.735998+05:30",
  "CreatedBy": "sample string 10",
  "Client": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "sample string 2",
    "ContactPersonName": "sample string 3",
    "ContactPersonMobile": "sample string 4",
    "ContactPersonEmail": "sample string 5",
    "CreatedOn": "2017-10-11T12:06:33.735998+05:30",
    "CreatedBy": "sample string 7",
    "Albums": []
  },
  "PhotoGrapher": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "sample string 2",
    "ContactPersonName": "sample string 3",
    "ContactPersonMobile": "sample string 4",
    "ContactPersonEmail": "sample string 5",
    "CreatedOn": "2017-10-11T12:06:33.735998+05:30",
    "CreatedBy": "sample string 7",
    "Albums": []
  },
  "Photos": []
}
  },
  {
"Id": 1,
"AlbumId": 2,
"Name": "sample string 3",
"Url": "sample string 4",
"ShareUrl": "sample string 5",
"Selected": true,
"Comment": "sample string 6",
"Album": {
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "sample string 2",
  "PhotoGrapherId": 3,
  "ClientId": 4,
  "EventType": "sample string 5",
  "EventDate": "2017-10-11T12:06:33.735998+05:30",
  "Status": "sample string 7",
  "Url": "sample string 8",
  "CreatedOn": "2017-10-11T12:06:33.735998+05:30",
  "CreatedBy": "sample string 10",
  "Client": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "sample string 2",
    "ContactPersonName": "sample string 3",
    "ContactPersonMobile": "sample string 4",
    "ContactPersonEmail": "sample string 5",
    "CreatedOn": "2017-10-11T12:06:33.735998+05:30",
    "CreatedBy": "sample string 7",
    "Albums": []
  },
  "PhotoGrapher": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "sample string 2",
    "ContactPersonName": "sample string 3",
    "ContactPersonMobile": "sample string 4",
    "ContactPersonEmail": "sample string 5",
    "CreatedOn": "2017-10-11T12:06:33.735998+05:30",
    "CreatedBy": "sample string 7",
    "Albums": []
  },
  "Photos": []
}
 }
 ]
```

I want to deserialize that json data in my cutom object and access each property dynamically.

i tried as follow

```
                           PhotoJson myListObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhotoJson>(responseText, settings);
```

and PhotoJson.cs

```
class PhotoJson
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string AlbumId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string ShareUrl { get; set; }

    public string Selected { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

}
```

Please any help me get it sort out my problem.i am not getting ore help on net also.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Json is usually a List of your class object

Using the following would do the trick

```
 List<PhotoJson> myListObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhotoJson>(responseText, settings);
```

or

```
 var myListObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhotoJson>(responseText, settings);
```

And then Simply using Linq to get the specific data would do the trick.

And i'm pretty sure the model class you have created is not proper you should update it as per the what Json is returning or else things wont work properly